# Upload issue Geonode

Tags: django

I am working on a website based on opensource Geonode. While extending the upload document section  - **(Hidden field permissions) This field is required.** shows up.

I didnt touch the geonode code. just added header and footer of personal choice.

[image]

Comment: Which geonode version raise this issue?

Comment: I fixed it... i was using 2 sets of headers. I omitted my custom headers and used the default geonode elements.